# Multiple SERIAL_EXECUTORS for AsyncTask

Tags: android, multithreading, android-asynctask

I am working on a app that syncs data over the network, and inserts user data in a database. To avoid slowing down the UI thread, both database queries and network requests run in the background.

At the moment, both are implemented using `AsyncTask`, started with `executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.SERIAL_EXECUTOR)`. The problem is, if a network request is taking a long time, database writes will be delayed by that much. Is it possible to have multiple `SERIAL_EXECUTORS` (in this case, two)?

If not, would the basic implementation of `SerialExecutor` shown in [Google's documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/Executor.html) be enough?

Comment: Have you tried using `THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR` instead? I don't think you can have multiple `SERIAL_EXECUTOR` as I think they share a queue. Also an idea for you is to use an `AsyncTaskLoader`. With the loader you can do both DB and HTTP calls in whichever order you want and return data to the UI when ready. http://developer.android.com/guide/components/loaders.html

Comment: I have considered it, but I want to keep database queries running in order, and network queries in order as well. If I use `THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR`, then multiple `DatabaseTask` could run at the same time for example, which I do  not want.

Comment: You can sync your DB methods with a `lock` to make sure they don't run at the same time. But in general, i'd suggest looking into `AsyncTaskLoader`. You might still ending up synchronizing around a lock for your DB methods for when you have multiple loaders running at the same time